# How to read from SQL Server table with RhinoETL framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, rhino-etl

Many sample codes on RhinoETL talk about loading from csv files and insert into database. How to perform a read from SQL Server database and output its rows to console ? Do you have a sample code to perform simple dbread and batch read ?

The [author's blog](https://ayende.com/blog/3102/rhino-etl-2-0) showed some sample code, but it appears to be incomplete, or I am missing something.

My non-working code

```
public class ReadBuildInfos : ConventionInputCommandOperation
{
    public ReadBuildInfos(ConnectionStringSettings csSettings) : base(csSettings)
    {
        Command = "SELECT Key, Value FROM dbo.BuildInfos WITH (NOLOCK);";
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Row> Execute(IEnumerable<Row> rows)
    {
        foreach (Row row in rows)
        {
            yield return row;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging directly with Rhino.Etl, turns out I did 2 mistakes:

1. The `ConnectionStringSettings` should include `providerName` . RhinoETL threw an exception on this but somehow I am not able to see it

   ```
       var csString = new ConnectionStringSettings("myConnection2",
           "Server=yourdatabasehere.database.windows.net;Database=MyDbName;User ID=youruser;Password=yourpassword",
           "System.Data.SqlClient"); //I was missing this.
       Register(new ReadBuildInfosConvention(csString));
   ```
2. The author's blog is complete. `Execute` method should not be overriden. A SQL Reader is as simple as the following:

   ```
   public class ReadBuildInfosConvention : ConventionInputCommandOperation
   {
       public ReadBuildInfosConvention(ConnectionStringSettings csSettings) : base(csSettings)
       {
           Command = "SELECT [Key], [Value] FROM BuildInfos WITH (NOLOCK);";
       }
   }
   ```

because the base `Execute` method already handles the DB Read appropriately

```
    public override IEnumerable<Row> Execute(IEnumerable<Row> rows)
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = Use.Connection(ConnectionStringSettings))
        using (IDbTransaction transaction = BeginTransaction(connection))
        {
            using (currentCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                currentCommand.Transaction = transaction;
                PrepareCommand(currentCommand);
                using (IDataReader reader = currentCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        yield return CreateRowFromReader(reader);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (transaction != null) transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Here is a working [VS solution with logging](https://github.com/mjeson/RhinoETLSampleDemo).